# DB2 Statistical View has no effect on cardinality estimates

Tags: sql, db2, sqlperformance

I have a table, let's call it `ACTIONS`, that has about 11 million rows. One of the columns, `ACTION_DATE`, says when this thing occurred. I want to run a daily report on actions taken yesterday, but occasionally I want to run a report from a long time ago. The table contains data going about 3 years back.

The distribution on the `ACTION_DATE` column is very skewed. Sometimes a day will have > 50k actions, and other days it'll just be a few hundred. I've done a `RUNSTATS` on this table and it quickly fills its frequency list with entries from years past, and this causes db2 to miscalculate the cost of accessing that table and leads to a bad execution plan.

I've read about Statistical Views, and thought this might help solve the problem. So I made one like this:

```
create view actions_recent as (select * from actions where action_date between current date - 90 days and current date);
alter view actions_recent enable query optimization
runstats on table actions_recent with distribution default num_freqvalues 90
```

But it seems to have no effect on the cost estimate or the query plan.

On the other hand, if I manually insert the cardinality of a particular day into the `SYSSTAT` table:

```
update sysstat.coldist set colvalue='2013-08-15',valcount=48562 where tabname='ACTIONS' and colname='ACTION_DATE' and seqno=1
```

and explain the access plan for the query on that day, I see that it picks up the info and adjusts costs accordingly.

What's wrong with my statistical view?

Comment: Did you recollect stats as "yesterday" might be out of the range of dates covered by the stats?

Comment: Stats have been collected for the `ACTIONS` table before running the explain plan. As I mentioned, hardcoding the date in question by updating sysstat.coldist was noticed by the optimizer, but the view's stats aren't.

Comment: Please post the query you're hoping will be improved by the stat view and the output from `db2exfmt`.

Comment: I will try to post it tomorrow. But basically, I keep seeing db2 documentation and official articles that say extremely-off-base cardinality estimates are very harmful. And this query has a number of those, to the point where the final estimate is 0.006 rows while the actual number is 91532 or something. WAY off. Most of the tables have millions or billions of records, over many years, and I need to narrow the statistics down to a particular date range. If statistical views aren't the solution, I could try writing my own runstats-like program, but I want to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Stats Views, like optimizer profiles, are a solution for very specific problems.  But you should try resolving the issue with other means first, reverting to a stats view only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: What other solutions could I try? I don't know a whole lot about DB2, and every now and then I come upon new useful info, but my toolbox right now is limited to runstats (with increased num_freqvalues) and tuning the query itself.